# Magetno 2 : How to create ui_component admin form?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

How to create ui_component admin form ??

I've checked [this](https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-1/) but as usual its not working so far.

Comment: Please check this sample module https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent

Answer (score 0):

You can check below tutorial for `ui_component` admin form.

[Link](https://www.pierrefay.com/magento2-training/form-component-backend-crud-admin.html)

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Already did, I've custom gird with PHP form, Would like to convert it in to `ui_component` form.

Comment: add your code in question and what issue you are getting, after that anyone help you.